# Getting data into Silverlight app

Tags: .net, silverlight, entity-framework

I am new to Silverlight (and .NET as well, for the most part) and am working on creating a Silverlight business application.  I followed the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796239%28v=vs.91%29.aspx and everything seems to work fine except for one problem:  not all tables/data is making its way over.

I am using Windows XP SP3, Microsoft SQL server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 for reference.

I created the app in VS as the default template for a Silverlight Business Application.  I then created the SQL connection to my database.  Then, following the tutorial, I created the Entity classes and then the Domain Service, just as the tutorial says to.

Alright, so here is what happens: I dragged and dropped a data grid onto a XAML form.  The first one worked just fine and displays the data rows correctly.  The second one does not, instead it throws the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:
>   Load operation failed for query
>   'GetMyData'. The remote server
>   returned an error: NotFound. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. --> System.Net.WebException:
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. --> System.net.WebException:
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. 
>   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) ...

This error appears as a pop-up from the web page when I try to navigate to it.

I have stepped through the Service.cs class on the GetMyData function and placed a watch on the data to be returned.  It shows that there is data, and I can even see the individual line items it is supposedly returning, so I just can't see the error anywhere.

Why does this work for some tables and not others?  Has anybody else seen this error?  I have seen a couple of pages that mention adding httpbindings and service tags to the web.config, but following their examples didn't work either.  As a matter of fact, when I do add them it makes the entire app not compile.

Is there a piece of configuration that I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This error depends on the size of the result set. In my sample the domainService throws NotFound while getting more than 9000 records.

To proof this, create a temporary Table as a copy of one of the failed tables. Then insert top 200 records of the original data and try to open that temp table in your SL-Application. Keep running your app you can delete the entries and fill it with top 15000 original records. Refresh your app, then... boom.

Looks like we need some kind of paging.

Comment: I noticed something similar, however, it worked for 1 row, and anything more than one row it produced the error.  I tried this by ensure there were two rows in the DB, which caused the error.  I removed one of them and it worked fine.  I agree that it might be a paging issue, but paging of one?  And how do you correctly set up this paging (I have seen some sites try to explain, but nothing worked)?